# What stopped the British from granting independence to the Andaman and Nicobar Islands?

Tags: india, british-empire, decolonization, myanmar

On the Wikpedia article about the [History of the Andaman and Nicobar Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Andaman_and_Nicobar_Islands):

> During the independence of both India (1947) and Burma (1948), the departing British announced their intention to resettle all Anglo-Indians and Anglo-Burmese on these islands to form their own nation, although this never materialized.

Why did this plan fail to materialize?

I tried to search for the source on Google, but all of the results repeat the same claim without citations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On 30 June 1947 (one and a half months before the independence of India), there was a discussion in the UK House of Commons about [Anglo-Indians and Europeans](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1947-06-30/debates/76fed0a7-9cfd-43aa-98cb-9e7f08658219/India) ([alternative link](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1947/jun/30/anglo-indians-and-europeans)):

> Mr. Gammons asked the Under-Secretary of State for India what reply he
>   has sent, or proposes to send, to the request made by the Anglo-Indian and domiciled European communities of India that they should be established in a homeland of their own and that, in particular, facilities should be provided for them to settle in the Andaman and Nicobar islands.
>
> The Under-Secretary of State for India (Mr. Arthur Henderson): A representation has been received from a body called the Britasian League of Calcutta, but **it is not considered that any such scheme is practical or desirable, particularly in view of the policy of the Anglo-Indian Association, which regards this scheme as impracticable.**
>
> Mr. Gammans: Do the Government accept in principle the responsibility for finding a homeland for the Anglo-Indian community, for whom we have a special responsibility, if they do not desire to remain either in Hindustan or Pakistan?
>
> Mr. Henderson: That is a hypothetical question. The only information which we have is a statement made in February of this year on behalf of the Anglo-Indian Association, that while it is not against individuals emigrating if they choose, it will not officially sponsor any such idea.

Note that there is a typo in the document: "Mr. Gammons" should be ["Mr. Gammans"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Gammans).

Comment: The Nicobars already had a self-sufficient population on them and probably could not have accepted a large influx of other people.

Comment: @Jurp: Looking at the small size of those islands, it seems unlikely that you could even fit the entire Anglo-Indian population on them, at least without turning them into something like Singapore or Manhattan.

Comment: @jamesqf - It's a good thing this resettlement wasn't attempted because most of the islands were hit by a tsunami in the early 2000s.A few were completely washed over by the wave and one island split into three. The loss of life was bad, but imagine if they'd added a quarter of million people to the islands 60 years earlier.

Comment: @Jurp Of course they took the tsunami that would happen over 50 years from then into consideration!